# Apply custom made function to pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, recursion

I have defined the following function that searches through the nested dictionaries for a value of a specific key.

```
def get_recursively(search_dict, field):

    fields_found = []

    if len(search_dict) == 1:
        search_dict = search_dict[0]

    for key, value in search_dict.items():

        if key == field:
            fields_found.append(value)

        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            results = get_recursively(value, field)
            for result in results:
                fields_found.append(result)

        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for item in value:
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    more_results = get_recursively(item, field)
                    for another_result in more_results:
                        fields_found.append(another_result)

    return fields_found
```

Now let's say I want to apply this function to a column in pandas df and save the result in a new column. My data looks like this:

```
id              metadata                    field
123             {"dek": "fashion...}        frontend
124.            {"dek": "house...}          frontend
```

I tried the following code:

```
df['NewCol'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_recursively(x['metadata'], x['field']), axis=1)
```

So in this case I am passing the column `metadata` and the value of the column `field` which is 'frontend' as arguments. I got an error: `KeyError: (0, 'occurred at index 2')` When I tested my function on one nested dictionary saved in a variable it gave me exactly what I needed, which is the value of a key - frontend. What am I doing wrong here?

An example of nested dicts that I am dealing with is provided below:

```
{"dek": "<p>Don\'t forget to buy a card</p>", "links": {"edit": {"dev": "//patty-menshealth.feature.hearstapps.net/en/content/edit/76517422-96ad-4b5c-a24a-c080c58bce0c", "prod": "//patty-menshealth.prod.hearstapps.com/en/content/edit/76517422-96ad-4b5c-a24a-c080c58bce0c", "stage": "//patty-menshealth.stage.hearstapps.net/en/content/edit/76517422-96ad-4b5c-a24a-c080c58bce0c"}, "frontend": {"dev": "//menshealth.feature.hearstapps.net/trending-news/a19521193/fathers-day-weekend-plans/", "prod": "//www.menshealth.com/trending-news/a19521193/fathers-day-weekend-plans/", "stage": "//menshealth.stage.hearstapps.net/trending-news/a19521193/fathers-day-weekend-plans/"}}, "header": {"title_color": 1, "title_layout": 1}, "sponsor": {"program_type": 1, "tracking_urls": []}, "social_dek": "<p>Don\'t forget to buy a card</p>", "auto_social": 0, "index_title": "\u200bWeekend Guide: Treat Your Dad Right This Father\'s Day", "short_title": "Treat Your Dad Right This Father\'s Day", "social_title": "\u200bWeekend Guide: Treat Your Dad Right This Father\'s Day", "editors_notes": "<p>nid: 2801076<br>created_date: 2017-06-16 13:00:01<br>compass_feed_date: 2017-06-21 14:01:58<br>contract_id: 40</p>", "seo_meta_title": "Treat Your Dad Right This Father\'s Day\u200b | Men’s Health", "social_share_url": "/trending-news/a19521193/fathers-day-weekend-plans/", "seo_related_links": {}, "editor_attribution": "by", "hide_from_homepage": 1, "syndication_rights": 3, "seo_meta_description": "\u200bFrom gifts to food ideas, we\'ve got your Father\'s Day covered. Just don\'t forget to buy him a card."}
```

Comment: Make sure your metadata is dictonary object. Also double check column names.

Comment: @Poojan When I ran `print(type(df['metadata']))` it says: `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Comment: Instead of `apply` i think you could just use list comprehension: `df["NewCol"] = [get_recursively(*a) for a in zip(df["metadata"],df["field"])]`.

Comment: @HenryYik Ran your code and got an error: `KeyError: 0` :/

Comment: So its your function's problem. Probably at the line `search_dict = search_dict[0]`.

Comment: You need to check `type(df.loc[0,'metadata'])`

Comment: Thank you! Checked! <class 'dict'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key error seemed to be caused by the first if statement:

```
if len(search_dict) == 1:
    search_dict = search_dict[0]
```

I had issues with the Dict type checking, and opted to try with collections.Mapping instead of dict. I tested the solution below and it seemed to work.

```py
import collections

def get_recursively(search_dict, field):

    fields_found = []
    for key, value in search_dict.items():

        if key == field:
            fields_found.append(value)

        elif isinstance(value, collections.Mapping):
            results = get_recursively(value, field)
            for result in results:
                fields_found.append(result)

        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for item in value:
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    more_results = get_recursively(item, field)
                    for another_result in more_results:
                        fields_found.append(another_result)

    return fields_found
```